# Match order of polynomial output in R and Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, polynomials, poly

I need to compare the output of a third-degree polynomial matrix between Python and R. The values seem to match but the order is off. Is there a way to order the poly output in R to match that of Python?

Example data: x = 2,3,4,5,6

**Python Code:**

```
X = np.vstack([2,3,4,5,6]).T

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
```

**Python Output:**

array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.,  12.,
9.,  12.,  15.,  18.,  16.,  20.,  24.,  25.,  30.,  36.,   8.,
12.,  16.,  20.,  24.,  18.,  24.,  30.,  36.,  32.,  40.,  48.,
50.,  60.,  72.,  27.,  36.,  45.,  54.,  48.,  60.,  72.,  75.,
90., 108.,  64.,  80.,  96., 100., 120., 144., 125., 150., 180.,
216.]])

**R Code:**

```
x <- t(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
dx <- c(1, as.numeric(poly(x, degree = 3, raw=TRUE)))
```

**R Output:**

[1]   1   2   4   8   3   6  12   9  18  27   4   8  16  12
[15]  24  36  16  32  48  64   5  10  20  15  30  45  20  40
[29]  60  80  25  50  75 100 125   6  12  24  18  36  54  24
[43]  48  72  96  30  60  90 120 150  36  72 108 144 180 216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
x <- t(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
p <- poly(x, degree = 3, raw=TRUE)
c(1, p[order(-attr(p, "degree"), colnames(p), decreasing = TRUE)])
#[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   4   6   8  10  12   9  12  15  18  16  20  24  25  30  36   8  12  16  20  24  18  24  30  36  32
#[32]  40  48  50  60  72  27  36  45  54  48  60  72  75  90 108  64  80  96 100 120 144 125 150 180 216
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately, I am not allowed to upvote the answer. But I remember to do so once I have enough points!

Comment: @Globoquadrina You can press the green tick mark (which "accepts" the answer). I believe doing so even gives you some points.